# Python Debugging in Jupyter - view value without typing variable name

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In MATLAB, while debugging, if you hover the mouse cursor over a variable, you can see the current value of that variable.
Is there a feature in Jupyter like this? Typing the variable each time in pdb.set_trace() is not very convenient.

I haven't found anything in Jupyter Help like that. Is there anything similar to MATLAB in Jupyter?

Thank you

Comment: Which `jupyter` interface are you using?  Notebook?  qtconsole? console?

Comment: I am using Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

LSP has this feature: https://github.com/jupyter-lsp/jupyterlab-lsp

It is a practically industry wide standard.

It is also being integrated in Jupyter Lab as a native solution, so you dont have to bother with separate installation